# Regex to extract specific words

Tags: regex

I am looking for regex to extract following words from text.  For example, the word which comes after "Replaced" in each of these lines:

```
Replaced disk 

Replaced floppy

Replaced memory
```

Please suggest the regex for it.

Comment: Do you want to extract both words or just the second one?

Answer (score 1):

We can't really help you without more details (like which regex flavor you're using, for example), but you probably want to match it with something like this:

```
Replaced\s+(\w+)\b
```

...and then extract the desired portion from capturing group #1.

Answer (score 0):

use this regex `(?<=Replaced\s*)(.+)`

Comment: Does NSRegularExpression supports variable width look-behind? Edit: It won't work, according to [ICU regex](http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp), which NSRegularExpression is based on.

Comment: i don't know, if not - `?<=Replaced\s*.+` with manual splitting

Comment: Do we even know if the OP is using NSRegularExpression?  Newcomers tend to use that tag incorrectly, not realizing `regex` is the correct and only tag for regexes in general.  I'm pretty sure that's the case here.

Answer (score 0):

I think

```
/Replaced\s(\w*?)/
```

Or:

```
/(?<=Replaced\s)(\w*)/
```

If you only want to select the word and not `Replaced`.